# New Facebook share API

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

Seems like the latest Facebook Share API has dropped a couple of parameters and is now down to a lean

```
    FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){})
```

It now relies solely on OpenGraph tags in the page HEAD.

Unfortunately, I have a couple of use cases where we may want the user to share the page but possibly also share a "quick app" somewhere in the right rail.

The only solution I can think of for the Quick app would be to point the href to a lander page that features just the app with the correct OG tags in the head.. and just the app contents.

This this seem like the best approach or have I missed a step?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a bad solution, but you can also use the feed dialog and add all the information on your own: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

Comment: Isn't Feed going to be out of business soon? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/deprecated

Comment: Wait now... it isn't deprecated... as of 2.5 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5 Just two parameters

Comment: it was deprecated several months ago, but it isn´t deprecated anymore. not sure what you mean with "two parameters", just scroll down... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5#params